Questionable step in an inequality
In a proof of some geometric property I read this:

The desired inequality becomes equivalent to
$$
\begin{aligned}
16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^{11 / 3} & \sum_c\color{blue}{[(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}}(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} z^{1 / 3} \\
& \leq 27\left[\prod_c(x+y)\right]^{13 / 3}\left[\prod_c(x+2 y+z)\right]^{2 / 3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using AM-GM we get $(8 x y z)^{1 / 3} \leq(x+y)^{2 / 3}(2 z)^{1 / 3}$, and thus it is sufficient to show that
$$
16 \cdot 2^{1 / 3}(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^{10 / 3} \sum_c(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} z^{2 / 3} \leq 27\left[\prod_c(x+y)\right]^{11 / 3}\left[\prod_c(x+2 y+z)\right]^{2 / 3} .
$$

What happened here? I see that we got
$$
(8 x y z)^{11 / 3}\leq (8 x y z)^{10 / 3}(x+y)^{2 / 3}(2 z)^{1 / 3}
$$
and then divided by $(x+y)^{2 / 3}$ somehow and the $2$ and the $z$ split up, the $z^{1 / 3}$ got into the sum, but:

$\color{blue}{[(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}}$ just vanished in the first sum
I do not understand why we can divide by $(x+y)^{2 / 3}$ and get $27\left[\prod_c(x+y)\right]^{11 / 3}$ on the right side $(13/3 \rightarrow 11/3)$. Why can you drag stuff into cyclic products and cyclic sums? Thats what the $c$ stands for btw.

Maybe someone sees what happenes here. All the numbers $x,y,z$ are strictly positive.
Note that $a=x+y,\, b=y+z,\, c=z+x$ are the sides of a triangle. The variables $x,y,z$ are the lengths from the corners of the triangle to the point where the incircle touches the triangle.

What happened is that the upper bound for $(8xyz)^{1/3}$ from the mentioned inequality was put into the cyclic sum. Since $(8xyz)^{1/3}$ is symmetric in all 3 variables that works. The given inequality is the version for the summand that is explicitely stated, but it is of course also true in the cycled versions.
So we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^\color{blue}{11 / 3}  \sum_c[(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} z^{1 / 3} \\
 & \le 16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^\color{blue}{10 / 3}\sum_c \color{blue}{(x+y)^{2/3}(2z)^{1/3}}[(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} z^{1 / 3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Both sides differ in the factor before the cyclic sum in the marked exponent (in blue), and that factor $(8xyz)^{1/3}$ has been replaced on the right hand side by the value the AM-GM inequality gave (also in blue).
We can now simplify the right hand side a bit
$$
\begin{aligned}
 & 16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^{10 / 3}\sum_c \color{blue}{(x+y)^{2/3}(2z)^{1/3}}[(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} z^{1 / 3} \\
= & 16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^{10 / 3}\sum_c [\color{blue}{(x+y)}(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} \color{blue}{2^{1/3}} z^{\color{blue}2 / 3} 
\end{aligned}
$$
where the new blue parts are distributed as shown.
Note that the factor $[(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}$ that was obtained that way is now symmetric (it doesn't change when the variables cycle), so it can be moved outside the cyclic sum. $[(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)]$ is actually just $\prod_c (x+y)$. The constant factor $2^{1/3}$ can also be moved outside the cyclic sum. So we can simplify the right has side of the last obtained term to
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^{10 / 3}\sum_c \color{blue}{[(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)]^{2 / 3}}(x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} \color{blue}{2^{1/3}} z^{2 / 3} \\
=& 16(x+y+z)^2(8 x y z)^{10 / 3} \color{blue}{2^{1/3}\prod_c{(x+y)}^{2/3}}\sum_c (x+y+2 z)^{1 / 3} z^{2 / 3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now the only step left to what has been stated int the proof is to divide by $\prod_c{(x+y)}^{2/3}$ on both side of what the proof claims, explaining the reduction from $\prod_c{(x+y)}^{13/3}$ to $\prod_c{(x+y)}^{11/3}$ on the right hand side of the inequality that is left to prove.
